# How to make Repl.it hidden test cases

Tags: python, replit

I'm part of an organization where we teach basic programming to highscholers. And we just switched the exercices grading platform because the old one went down. For the new one, we chose Repl.it because of its flexibility but there is a HUGE problem in it, all the test cases of input/output are public. Some students could simply use 'if' statements and bypass the whole question.

Any idea of how to solve this, without using unit testing? We accept new platform suggestions.

Its important to have hidden cases, so we can keep the autograding system. There are more than 150 students per class, so completely not viable to manually correct each exercise.

Comment: its pretty trivial to write your own ... or you could use something like hackerrank or codesignal but those will charge you ... i think there judge0 which is an open source platform for executing submitted code, that could help if you made your own and didnt want to setup containers and stuff to run the submitted codes

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple "grader" in about 35 lines of python and a few lines of docker

##### server.py

```py
import json
import os
import time
import flask
from flask import request, Response

app = flask.Flask("__main__")

@app.route("/submit",methods=["GET","POST"])
def submit_code():
    print(request.files)
    if request.files.get("CODE"):
        submitted_file = request.files['CODE']
        user_id = request.form['uid']
        save_dir = f"/tmp/{user_id}"
        save_dir = r"E:\waveCollapseTest"
        save_path = f"{save_dir}/{int(time.time())}-{submitted_file.name}"

        os.makedirs(save_dir,exist_ok=True)
        request.files["CODE"].save(save_path)
        result = os.popen(f"docker run -v {save_dir}:/submission MyDockerImage:Assignment15")
        return Response(f"Thank you for your submission\nRESULTS: {result}/15 Test Cases Passed")
        # code is submitted
    else:
        return Response('''<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method="post"><input name="uid" placeholder="user id"/><input type="file" name="CODE" /><input type="submit"/>''')

app.run()
```

##### run_tests.py

```py
import json
ttl = 0
passed=0
for entry in json.loads(open("testcases.json")):
    passed += os.popen("python /submission/*.py {entry['input']}").read().strip() == entry['expected']
    ttl += 1
print(f"Passed {passed}/{ttl}")
```

##### Dockerfile

```
from python:3.9
COPY run_tests.py run_tests.py
COPY test_cases.json test_cases.json
CMD="python run_tests.py"
```